# Clocking Wizard Vivado VHDL

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I'm doing a project with an FPGA on Vivado.

My FPGA has a 100 MHz clock, but I need a 22.57 MHz clock for my project, so I used the clocking wizard.

My problem is that, as the 22.5 MHz clock is an output of the clocking wizard, I cannot use it as an input on my system, so I cannot check for rising edges and so.

What would be the way to implement it so I can do it?

This is the code I have so far:

```
entity clk_generator is
   port(
   
    clk : in std_logic;     --(100 MHz)
    mclk_i : in std_logic;   --(22.579 MHz)
    
    mclk_o : out std_logic;  --(22.579 MHz)
    bclk : out std_logic;   --MCLK/8
    lrclk : out std_logic  --SCLK/64
    
    );
    
end clk_generator;



architecture Behavioral of clk_generator is

component clk_wiz_0
  port ( 
    mclk : out std_logic;
    clk_in1 : in std_logic
  );
    end component;

   signal bclk_couter: integer := 0;
   signal lrclk_couter : integer  := 0; 
   
begin

clk_gen : clk_wiz_0

port map(
    
    clk_in1 => clk,
    mclk => mclk_i    --IM GETTING THE ERROR HERE
   
    );
```

I need to use the `mclk` signal as an input of my system.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I just found a solution; I just created a signal named `mclk` instead of an input signal, and it worked ok.

This is the code:

```
    entity clk_generator is
   port(
   
    clk : in std_logic;     --(100 MHz)
    
    
    mclk_o : out std_logic;  --(22.579 MHz)
    bclk : out std_logic;   --MCLK/8
    lrclk : out std_logic  --SCLK/64
    
    );
    
end clk_generator;



architecture Behavioral of clk_generator is

component clk_wiz_0
  port ( 
    mclk : out std_logic;
    clk_in1 : in std_logic
  );
    end component;
   signal mclk_i : std_logic;
   signal bclk_couter: integer := 0;
   signal lrclk_couter : integer  := 0; 
   
begin

clk_gen : clk_wiz_0

port map(
    
    clk_in1 => clk,
    mclk => mclk_i   
    
    );
```